# Flutter/Supabase - how to add 'distinct' to data select?

Tags: flutter, supabase-database, supabase-flutter

From my Flutter app, when querying Supabase, is there a way to apply a 'distinct(field_name)' to the select clause?

Comment: You will need to create a database function and call it via rpc() method. 
https://supabase.com/docs/guides/database/functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for now it is no possible to use distinct but you can create a function or a view that return your data correcly